# Vetting a random number generator -- Chi Square Tests throws varying p-value results

Tags: statistics, simulation, chi-squared

Suppose I have a random number generator and I want to check with a Chi Square Test whether its pdf is uniform or no. I can write a script that does that and I will run it several times. To my surprise, I get completely different results each times. Sometimes I will get a p-value of 0.3, sometimes 0.987 and other times 0.003. Which is the number I should take? Should I try to get an average of the p-values I get? How do I decide if this generator passes the test or not?

So what I try next is using a random number generator that I already "know" to be uniform and I run the test on that. And I keep getting absolutely varying results. Even if I increase the number of samples, it keeps varying a lot! From what I understad, the probability if seeing a very low p-value when drawing random samples from a uniform distribution should be low, and the probability of seeing a high p-value should be high. But this doesn't seem to happen.

How should I interpret the results I get from this test?

This is the Python script I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chisquare

bins=256
x = np.random.randint(bins, size=bins*100)

h = [];
for i in range(bins):
  h.append(0);

for n in range(0, len(x)):
  h[x[n]] += 1;

print(chisquare(h))
```

and this are the results I get:

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=303.19999999999999, pvalue=0.020572599306529871)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=211.06, pvalue=0.97933788750272888)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=289.66000000000003, pvalue=0.066874498546635575)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=275.63999999999999, pvalue=0.17885688588645363)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=257.86000000000001, pvalue=0.43814613213884313)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=217.07999999999998, pvalue=0.95911527563656596)
```

Even more, I did a histogram of the p-values I got and it looks pretty uniform. If I know the samples I have are drawn from a uniform distribution, shouldn't I get most of the times a high p-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are vetting a random number generator (RNG), this chi-squared test 
is one useful criterion. However, there are some additional considerations:

(a) The chi-squared *statistic* is based on integer counts, and thus is
discrete. This means the P-values from the test will not be *exactly*
uniformly distributed in $(0,1).$ [The approximating chi-squared *distribution*
is continuous, but it is the statistic that matters.] Even though
the P-values are are not exactly $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ they will take 
many values throughout $(0,1)$ if the RNG is working as advertised.

(b) Even if the RNG is is 'good', the P-value will be below 0.05 in about 5%
of your runs. Thus it is necessary to do many runs (as you have done) before
drawing a conclusion about the RNG. You should be suspicious of an RNG that
consistently gives P-values below 0.05.

(c) Perhaps surprisingly, you should also be suspicious of an RNG that
consistently gives P-values *above* 0.95 (corresponding to very *low* chi-squared values). A frequent flaw in 'bad' RNGs is that their behavior is 'too regular'.
A chi-squared statistic of 0 arises from *perfect fit* of observed counts to
expected counts. Analogously, you should be suspicious if someone claims
to have rolled a fair die 600 times, obtaining exactly 100 instances each
of faces 1 through 6. The result seems "too good to be true."

*More generally,* thoroughly vetting an RNG requires subjecting it to a large
number of simulation tasks to see that it gets the same answers predicted
by theory. Some of the tests need to be multivariate, because it is possible
for an RNG to make a suitable almost uniform-looking histogram in one dimension
and yet put all its points on only a few hyperplanes of an $n$-dimensional
unit hypercube. [The "Mersenne-Twister," the default RNG in R statistical software, has been vetted up to $n = 623$ dimensions. If you have access to R,
type `help .Random.seed` and `help runif` in the Session window for
explanatory pages.]

There are curated 'batteries' of test problems for RNGs. Problems are chosen because they are
notoriously difficult for RNGs that are only 'pretty good' to simulate correctly. One useful package
of such problems is Marsaglia's "Die Hard," which you can read about on
several Internet pages.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [cross validated post.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10613/why-are-p-values-uniformly-distributed-under-the-null-hypothesis) With this you can answer half of your questions, but I will point things out.

The p value is a function of random data and so a random variable on its own. Thus, you expect it to vary with some distribution (as you discovered experimentally). When the null hypothesis is true (in this case that the data does come from the uniform distribution), you expect every p value to be equally likely i.e p to be uniformly distributed. Thus you are getting exactly the result that you should expect in your second example! Moreover, if the p value is uniformly distributed, you will most of the time get a "high" p value (for a reasonable value of high)!

As to what you should do with the p values and how you should interpret them/decide if the generator passes/fails, check out this other [cross validated post.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78596/when-combining-p-values-why-not-just-averaging) In short, you can just average them and interpret the result as one p value, but there are other more natural things that you can do that are typically better.

Comment: I am upvoting this answer because it was very helpful too.